# Handle Wcf wsHttpBinding on Linux

Tags: wcf, mono, wshttpbinding, wcf-wshttpbinding

I'm involved in a project with many others companies. We started to develop our systems at the same time but only at the end the communication problem was taken into account.
I've developed my system on Linux with Mono (Linux is mandatory for me). I have to communicate with a Windows .Net system which is exposing a Wcf web services. Unfortunately they told me only now they are using wsHttpBinding and I've just discovered that this communication protocol is not supported by Mono.

I'm here to ask if there is a way to communicate with that web service. They are not going to change the wsHttpBinding because is used by many other companies. I cannot change my OS and my code base is too big to leave Mono now. I can only add a layer (always on Linux) between my Mono implementation and their web services.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You could ask them to add *another* protocol. Webservices are not limited to a single protocol, they can offer multiple endpoints with multiple protocols.

Comment: @nvoigt thank you. I already asked for a basicHttpBinding endpoint but their answers are evasive and I cannot be sure they will implement anything. So I have to implement a B plan in case they will not expose another mono-compatible endpoint. I know this is not how things are supposed to be made, but unfortunately this is my current situation.

Comment: Yeah, our company has much wsHttpBinding services when I develop something like openapi which want to run on mono but can't because that my openapi need to call the wsHttpBinding services but mono doesn't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has recently released the .NET [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource) as MIT licence (open source).

This means that, if something is *not supported by Mono*, you can just bring the code yourself and incorporate it, so that it becomes officially supported.

Some Mono developers have actually been doing this the past weeks to incorporate things that they had not implemented yet. So you could bring the wsHttpBinding along to Mono. An example of such a change is [this commit](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/cfa8bc07f687c75b231fa8abed123d44da1c3a9b).